# Java String contain function?

Tags: java, string, contains

Is it possible to test for multiple substrings in the following string using contains()?

```
"details.php?news=13&action=main&menu_type=&option=single&news_id=4792&pub_no=50"
```

For example, can I check for `strcase="details.php"`, `"news_id"` to be checked at the same time using `str.contains(strcase)`?

I do not want to check like this: `str.contains("details.php")&&str.contains("news_id")`. because I want to check for both simultaneously: `strcase="details.php ** news_id"`

Like this statement :

```
str.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
```

can strip out tag `"<?>"`.

Answer (score 5):

`string.contains()` does not match regular expressions, so you cannot use it like `str.replace()`.

You could use [`string.matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) though, as it does accept regular expressions.

```
str.matches(".*details\\.php.*news_id.*");
```

**Disclaimer** I suck at regular expressions, but that should be close to what you want.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me, as long as "details" really has to be the first thing in the string. Otherwise, you'll need another `.*` in there.

Comment: Just FYI, `replace()` doesn't use regexes either; it's `replaceAll()` you're thinking of.